# Always return empty array when populate

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm new in NodeJS. I have a small example, with full directory

```
|
|----index.js
|----model
   |----user.js
   |----status.js
```

Content of model/user.js:

```
var uri = 'mongodb://localhost/demo1';
var db  = require('mongoose').connect(uri),
    Schema = db.Schema;

var UserSchema = new Schema({
    username: String,
    password: String,
    level: Number,
    status: Number,
    statusName: {type: Number, ref: 'Status'}
});

var User = db.model('User', UserSchema);

module.exports = User;
```

Content of model/status.js

```
var db = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = db.Schema;

var StatusSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    id: Number,
    user_status: [{
        type: Number,
        ref: 'User'
    }]
}, {
    collection: 'user_status'
});

var Status = db.model('UserStatus', StatusSchema);

module.exports = Status;
```

At least, index.js

```
var User   = require('./model/user');
var Status = require('./model/status');

Status
    .find({})
    .populate('statusName')
    .exec(function (err, data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
```

When run index.js by Terminal, I got data as

```
[{ _id: 55d596852b3d925575644f69,
    id: 1,
    name: 'Active',
    user_status: [] },
  { _id: 55d596902b3d925575644f6a,
    id: 2,
    name: 'Expired',
    user_status: [] },
  { _id: 55d596962b3d925575644f6b,
    id: 3,
    name: 'Locked',
    user_status: [] }
]
```

Why user_status property return empty? Any wrong code written?
Sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 0):

Your StatusSchema is incorrect. You need to override the `_id` field, which is the one being looked up by `.populate()`:

```
var StatusSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    _id: Number,
    user_status: [{
        type: Number,
        ref: 'User'
    }]
}, {
    collection: 'user_status',
    _id: false
});
```

So change the schema and your data to move from "id" to "_id". Which means you need to drop the collection and load it again. Or use a different collection, since you cannot change the `_id` value present in the collection already. It's immutable.